# Convert a list of IR codes into Lua array/table

Tags: lua

I’ve generated a long list of IR codes (via IrScrutinizer) in a text file (test.txt - example below), and I’d like to convert them into a table, or .csv, with their associated name as the variable name, so I can then call them.

Example text.

```
Power
0000 0070 0000 0032 0080 0040 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0ACD

Power$1
0000 006C 0022 0002 015B 00AD 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 05F7 015B 0057 0016 0E6C

Power$2
0000 0068 0000 0022 0169 00B4 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0636
```

I’m new to Lua, and have been trying to work out how to do it. I’ like to go and get the file, open it, and then do the conversion into an array or store that in a new file . And then be able to come back later and call the specific code(s) I need.

Conversion function.

```
function convertCodestoarray (filename)
  local lfs = require "lfs" 
  local dir = "mnt/nas/vera/ircodes/"   -- the path to the files 
  print(dir .. filename)
  for filename in lfs.dir(dir) do 
        if filename: match "%.txt$" then 
            for line in io.lines(dir .. filename) do 
                local params = "([^,]+)/n([^,]+)"
                local codename, prontocode = params
                local params = table.concat ({codename, prontocode}, ", ") 
                print(params)
        for filename2 in lfs.dir(dir) do 
        local filename2 = io.open("powerircodes.csv", 'a') 
        filename2:write(params .. "\n")
end
end

filename2:close()

end
end
end

convertCodestoarray("text1.txt")
```

Comment: 1) You've missed parentheses after `io.open()`, 2) There should be a second `end` after `file:close()`. 3) You have to choose where do you get your files from: `filename` or `lfs.dir(dir)`.

Comment: Thanks, updated above, and both (source and target) files are stored in the same folder/directory?

Comment: I am afraid that your code is still rather meaningless. The function argument `filename` is never used. The lines `local irtable = "powerircodes.csv"` and `for irtable in lfs.dir(dir) do ` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ok, thanks - the filename is passed as part of the function call, is that not a good route, also i’ve updated the original post with the latest version , sadly still no luck . Ultimately I just need to read that list if it codes and convert them into an array/ table or write them to a straightforward.csv